# Why does setting p element's vertical margins to 1 px make scrollbars appear?

Tags: html, css

`p` element without margin:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>p</p>
</body>

</html>
```

`p` element with margin:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>p</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Why does setting p tag's vertical margin to 1px make scrollbars appear?

Comment: Although setting the `overflow: hidden` in body will make scrollbar disappear but your question is about why the scrollbar is appearing which I am also curious about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Margin collapse. The p's top margin collapses with the body's margin, making the body's margin box height 100vh + 1px, which overflows the viewport, requiring the scrollbars.

If you stop the margin from collapsing by setting the body's display to flow-root, the scrollbars disappear.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display:flow-root;
}

p {
  margin: 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>p</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Neat trick with `flow-root`. Do you know of any potential side effects of establishing a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) on the `body`?

Comment: @Kameron - Sure, like everything in CSS, there's always a trade-off. A BFC will for example contain its floats (like a clear-fix), potentially making the body taller than it otherwise would be.

Comment: @Alohci i get that the p tag's top margin is collapsing with the body, which would make the body height at least 100vh + 1px. But why is it collapsing with the bottom margin as well, if the body's bottom margin is all the way at the bottom, far away from the p tag? Also, why do horizontal scrollbars appear if the vertical margins are collapsing?

Comment: @JoelCastro - My bad. You are correct. The bottom margins are not collapsing.  I have corrected my answer. The horizontal scrollbars appear because the body's width of 100vw is wider than the horizontal space available which is the viewport minus the width of the vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 2):

`p`'s are block-level which generate line breaks both before and after the element when in the normal flow. This allows for content to flow above or beneath instead of adjacent.

When you add `margin` to this it creates a [collapsed margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

When you use `inline-block` the element generates one or more inline element boxes that do not generate line breaks before or after themselves. In normal flow, the next element will be on the same line if there is space.

So when you set `p` to  `display: inline-block;` the scrollbar is removed.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 1px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>p</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't get how the line breaks affect the margins.